# Setting session_set_save_handler for one page only

Tags: php, session, handler

In my php.ini i have the following set:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379?weight=1"
```

But i want to keep that set as it works with this system im using but only thing is when i try create session it gives me errors.. Going off point.

Issue is, im trying to set the save handler then as files ONLY for my login.php and then after that use redis.

I have the following code in my file but doesnt change from redis to files:

```
session_set_save_handler('files');
session_save_path("/tmp/");
session_start(); // Starting Session
```

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: `Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (redis). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp/) in Unknown on line 0  `
Updated the result:

Comment: When i make the over all save_handler as files it works but i need it as redis for my sites structure. Redis works perfectly for me apart from this session issue when trying set a session on my login system. So im trying use files again just for login then resort back to redis?

Comment: You shouldn't use `tcp://localhost` there. PHP likely won't resolve `localhost` properly. Instead use `tcp://127.0.0.1` or whatever the IP address is that redis is listening on.

Comment: So @Sherif i should make it: `session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1"` ?

Comment: Well, obviously you want to include the port and any other authentication/weight parameters needed by your redis server, just like you have in your original string. You're simplying replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`session_set_save_handler` function](http://php.net/session-set-save-handler) doesn't exactly do the same thing as the [`session.set_handler` configuration](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.save-handler) directive. The former expects a [callable type](http://php.net/language.types.callable) as its first argument, whereas the latter expects a scalar value as one of the registered handlers in PHP.

What you want is to say `ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files')`.

When you set the `session.save_path` for the `redis` session handler, you should avoid using hostnames that can't be resolved directly through your DNS resolver. That's pretty much anything that you put in `/etc/hosts` like `localhost`. Instead, try using the IP address that redis is listening on directly, such as `127.0.0.1`. The reason for this is that PHP won't attempt to look at `/etc/hosts` directly when resolving the hostname.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it.